# What's the difference between "Save & Close", "Save", and "Publish" when editing a knowledge base article?

Tags: knowledge, articles

I'm confused on the difference between "Save & Close", "Save", and "Publish" when editing a pre-existing article.  Can someone please clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly....

**Save**: Saves the changes you made and stays on the article page, the article stays as a draft.

**Save & Close**: Saves the changes you made and goes back to the previous page, the article stays as a draft.

**Publish**: Publishes the draft article.

Comment: So if I'm happy with my draft and want to make it visible, I can click `Publish` and skip `Save`? That seems to commit my changes to the article as well.

Comment: @MikeB Correct.